# How can I listen to Windows events from a Java app?

Tags: java, winapi, events

I have a process written in C++ that raises a named event using CreateEvent.
Is there a java implementation of the WaitForSingleObject function?

Is there a better way to pass events between a C++ or .NET process and a Java process?

(I am aware of the option to use JNI to wrap whatever calls I want. I am looking for a library that already took care of it.)

thanks,

Ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technolgies which might be useful:

- [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/twall/jna/) provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries (DLLs on Windows) without writing anything but Java code—no JNI or native code is required.
- Message oriented Middleware which includes C/C++ drivers, for example [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [OpenMQ](https://mq.dev.java.net/) or [xmlBlaster](http://www.xmlblaster.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in the standard Java API, because that's a highly platform-specific Windows thing (and Java is platform-independent, so you won't find such Windows-only functionality in Java's standard API).

You could write some code in C++ and call it from your Java program using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).