# Run batch files according to the state of my explorer.exe in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to run some batch files according to the explorer.exe state.That is, i want to run a batch file when the desktop is active, and i wanna run another batch file if a drive in My Computer is opened and another different batch file if a folder inside that drive is opened.I wonder if there is anyway to get information necessary to get this done?..

Thanx in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660961/how-can-i-listen-to-windows-events-from-a-java-app

Comment: I came to know about JNA.I downloaded jna.jar and platform.jar..Added them to libraries..But don't know how to Operate with it.

Comment: Please somebody help... :(